# MVC Linq for multiple selects that allow multiple selections

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a MVC web application with multiple selects that allow multiple selections that the user can use to filter data. For example: A car database where the user can select by make, color and body style. A possible search would be (Red OR Blue) AND (Chevy OR Ford) AND (SUV). I have all the selects returned in my viewmodel as array of strings and all gets returned to my controller correctly. I have the Color array with 'Red' and 'Blue', the Model array with 'Chevy' and 'Ford' and the BodyStyle array with 'SUV'. Now that I have the model posted to the controller, how do I construct the linq statement that will allow and of these criteria to me blank or contain multiple selections?

Model:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public string[] Model { get; set; }
    public string[] Color { get; set; }
    public string[] Body { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel search)
{
    //TODO: Create linq for all search criteria
    List<Cars> cars = db.Cars.Where(car => car.Model == search.Model[0]);

    return View(cars);
}
```

Comment: can you give us a sample of you data where you want to perform the LINQ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You have a great description of what you are attempting to do, but have provided no code.  Please take a minute to read [Help Center > Asking > How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  It will benefit both you and the people trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = new List<string> { "red", "orange"};

    from c in DB.Cars
    where list == null || list.Contains(c.Color)
    select c;
```

Comment: When I try 
'db.Cars.Where(car => search.Color== null || search.Color.Contains(car.Color)).ToList();'
I get an error when doing the check for null: Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.

Comment: I initialize my list in the SearchViewModel and check if list count is zero:
List<Car> cars= db.Car.Where(car => search.Color.Count == 0 || search.Color.Contains(car.Color)).ToList();